# Can I use the Present Tense for events regarded at the present as immutably fixed?

Tags: verbs

In Italian, and American English, I could use the Present Tense for something happening in the future.

> Domani inizio il mio nuovo lavoro. (*Tomorrow I start my new job.*)

As said in the answer to [Can I always use the present tense for something happening in the future?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8078/can-i-always-use-the-present-tense-for-something-happening-in-the-future) American English uses the Present Tense for future events when these are regarded at the present as immutably fixed (e.g. schedules or timetables).

Can I use the Present Tense for the same purpose, in Esperanto? If not, what tense should I use for events regarded as immutably fixed?

On [*26.2.1. Nun-tempo: AS-finaĵo*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/reala/nun-tempo.html) there is the following example:

> Hodiaŭ mi studas Esperanton. (*Today I study Esperanto.*)

Since the sentence is talking of today, it is also talking of the future (*today* as *from the moment I am talking until the day is over*), I take the example could express an intention or it is talking of an event that at the present is regarded as fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you write "Mi baldaŭ foriras" instead of "Mi baldaŭ foriros"?](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/232/can-you-write-mi-balda%c5%ad-foriras-instead-of-mi-balda%c5%ad-foriros)

Comment: The other question is not about future events regarded at the present as immutably fixed. It is about using _baldaŭ_ with the Present Tense.

Comment: Whether it's "tomorrow" or "soon" makes no difference. Perhaps it is not a duplicate, but my answer there is just as valid here.

Comment: It makes a difference, since _soon_ is not used for _events regarded at the present as immutably fixed_. There is a difference between _I will soon go to the mall_ and _Tomorrow I go to the mall_. In fact, the first sentence is also used not to express certainty.

Comment: I meant that it does not make a difference *in Esperanto*; sorry if I was unclear. As I said in the linked question, the present tense in Esperanto is used for actions or states that have "started, but not finished." For future reference, it does not help to clarify your question if you simply repeat the same phrase ("events regarded at the present as immutably fixed") over and over; if you think somebody is not understanding you, rephrase instead of repeating.

Comment: Sorry, but from your answer to the other question is **not** clear if Esperanto uses the Present Tense in the same way as American English does. It is not that since you are answering a question about using _baldaŭ_, you are answering every question about the Future Tense.

Comment: *Everything* said in response to the *baldaŭ* question applies to this question as well, without any non-obvious changes. My answer there should also explain why that is the case.

Comment: @HansAdler The difference is that, for that question, it was just sufficient to say that _baldaŭ_ doesn't imply anything about when the action is happening, so it cannot replace the tense.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That *would* have been sufficient if it were true. But *baldaŭ* clearly specifies that it will happen in the future; up to the usual imprecisions of a human language it also specifies when. Max even stated as much in the second sentence of his answer. I am sure there are natural languages in which the additional consideration "can't be changed" plays an important role - in fact, there are probably languages that use past tense in this situation! - but this exception simply doesn't apply in Esperanto any more than a special exception that on Wednesdays you can use any tense.

Comment: @HansAdler You could say _I returned soon_, and that would not mean it happened in the future.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Even in your example, *soon* points to the future - as seen from a certain point of view in the past. It's like in some languages you can even say *Last Sunday I returned tomorrow*, referring to last Monday as the day of your return.

Comment: @HansAdler But if I tell you _I returned soon_, it is referring to the past of now, not to the future of now. If I tell you _she said "I will return soon"_, it is referring to the future of a past event, which could still be the past. So, _it is referring to the future_ is relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When read too literally, the statement that tense-marking in Esperanto is obligatory is only approximately correct and not totally helpful. As infinitives, verbs can be used without any tense-marking. And for the other verb forms, it's not just obligatory - all other verb forms are automatically marked for tense. What is really meant is that present tense in Esperanto is not a default tense that can sometimes be used instead of other tenses. The 'wrong' formulation of this principle probably comes from natural languages, where the present tense is often marked by the absence of special tense markers.

In most other languages, present tense is more fundamental than the other tenses, and amounts more or less to not marking for tense. Consequently, present tense verbs are ambiguous between actually meaning present tense and a more general use. (This is particularly relevant for languages which lack a future tense -- a very common phenomenon.) The resulting complications or ambiguities are completely unnecessary for Esperanto with its simple -is/-as/-os distinction. On the flip side, it is slightly harder for speakers of Germanic languages to express themselves in Esperanto because they must remember to always use it, even when it's clear they are talking about the future.

Comment: Not just the infinitive (_fari_) lacks tense marking, but also the conditional and imperative (_farus, faru_) are tenseless forms. You can say _Se mi hieraŭ farus tion, mi hodiaŭ pentus_, _Se mi morgaŭ farus tion, mi postmorgaŭ pentus_, _Faru tion postmorgaŭ, tuj kiam vi revenos de Parizo_).

Answer (score 4):

No. Tense-marking in Esperanto is obligatory; the fact that the future time is regarded as fixed does not make a difference. According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/reala/nun-tempo.html) (the Complete Handbook of Esperanto Grammar):

> AS-verbo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato estas reala, efektiva, kaj ke **ĝi komenciĝis, sed ne finiĝis.**
>
> *A verb ending with -as shows that the action or state is real, actual, and that **it has started, but not finished.***

(emphasis mine)

Thus, the present tense cannot be used for actions which have not yet started.

Comment: Re _Tense-marking in Esperanto is obligatory_: I didn't say I would not use any tense-marking.