# What adverb should I use in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

I am trying to translate *I come home not long after you arrive* in Esperanto. Google Translate gives me the following sentence.

> Mi venas hejmen post nelonge vi alvenas.

Should not *baldaŭ* be used instead of *post nelonge*, since its meaning is *post mallonga tempo* (*after not much time*)?

If I change the sentence, Google Translate uses *baldaŭ*.

> I come home soon after you arrive. (*Mi venas hejmen baldaŭ post vi alvenas.*)

To me, *post* seems already implicit in *baldaŭ*, and I would rather translate  the sentence with:

> Mi venas hejmen baldaŭ vi alvenas.

What adverb should I use for an action that happens soon after another action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider *tuj* ("straightaway"). However, one problem with using *baldaŭ* or *tuj* here is that it is unclear where the short time interval starts: now, or at the time of the other person's arrival. I'd suggest:

> Mi revenas hejmen nelonge post via alveno.
>
> Mi revenas hejmen nelonge post kiam vi alvenas.

Note that *antaŭ* and *post* become *antaŭ ol* and *post kiam* when followed by a clause.

To make it clear that you are describing what usually happens, not a single event, you can insert *kutime* or *ĝenerale* after *mi*.

Comment: Brilliant! I am so much used to use a clause, in English, that I forgot I could use a noun phrase.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say

> Mi venos hejmon *baldaŭ post kiam* vi alvenis.

Comment: I used the Present Tense because it is a fact, similar to _I am taller than my brother_. The sentence is not about a single event that will happens in the future.

Comment: @kiamlaluno In an [answer to another question that you recently asked](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/236/124) it was explained that Esperanto doesn't treat what you call "facts" in the way English treats them. If an event is not happening right now and will happen in the future, you use the future tense. There is no difference if the statement is considered to be 100000% certain thing. Future tense. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev I think this case is different from the other question and it makes sense to use the present tense here if it is describing a general rule. It could be describing the trend, ie it is something that has happened in the past and will continue to happen in the future.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev It's not me that calls them _facts_: "AS-verbo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato estas **reala, efektiva, kaj ke ĝi komenciĝis, sed ne finiĝis**."

Comment: @NeilRoberts Yes. It started (I already came back home right after that person), but it is not done yet (I still come back home right after that person).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I though the "coming home" is a future event, not a repeatable one.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev There is no need to be sorry. Trying to understand the question is necessary to give the correct answer, or to point the OP to a another question that could be of help, or be a duplicate.