# Sentempaj verboj Esperante

Tags: verbs, participles

Bonvolu pardoni min, ĉar ĉi tiu demando estas iom pedanta.

Mi scivolas kiel priskribi agojn aŭ okazaĵojn, kiuj ne havas definitan aŭ
sciitan tempon.

Iuj lingvoj havas verban aspekton sen specifa senco de tempo (angle,
*gnomic/generic aspect*), kiu priskribas generalajn verojn anstataŭ specifaj
okazaĵoj. Tamen, la plimulto da lingvoj (eŭropaj, almenaŭ) ne havas apartan
sentempan aspekton (*gnomic aspect*), sed anstataŭe uzas iun alian
aspekton/verbtempon kaj fidi la kuntekston por klarigi.

Ekzemple, la angla kutime uzas la *present continuous tense* anstataŭ la
*present tense* por priskribi nuntempajn okazaĵojn: "I am cooking." anstataŭ "I
cook.". Do, oni povas uzi la *present tense* por sentempaj okazaĵoj kaj ĝi
kutime estus komprenita kiel sentempa verbo: "I cook" signifas ke oni kuiremas
aŭ kapablas kuiri.

Aliekzemple, la franca kutime nur fidi la kuntekston por klarigi: "I am
cooking." kaj "I cook." kutime ambaŭ estas "Je cuisine.". Kvankam, oni ankaŭ
povas diri "Je suis en train de cuisiner." por la antaŭan.

Kiel oni farus ĝin en Esperanto? Laŭ tiu, kiun mi vidis, homoj ĉiam uzas "-as"
por ambaŭ la nuntempa (*present*) ambaŭ la sentempa (*gnomic*) kaj tute fidi la
kuntekston por senplursencigi. Mi havas kelkajn zorgojn pri ĉi tio.

## La uzo sentempa de "-as" estas iel kontraŭ la Fundamento laŭvorte.

La Fundamento tre klare diras ke la finaĵo "-as" estas la *present tense*:

> a) The present tense ends in as, e. g. mi far'as, „I do”.

> a) Le présent est caractérisé par as; ex.: mi far'as ― je fais.

Ĝi ne mencias la *gnomic/generic aspect* aŭ ion ajn similan.

Sed, kion precize signifas la *present tense* / *le présent*? En la angla kaj la
franca, la *present tense* estas ofte uzita kiel sentempa aspekto, sed, laŭvorte
parolante, la *present tense* ne estas la sentempa aspekto. Ĉu Esperanto do
heredu la sentempa uzo de la *present tense* el la angla kaj la franca, aŭ ne?

Pri ĉi tiu temo, la PMEG ŝajne memkontraŭdiras:

> AS-verbo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato estas reala, efektiva, kaj ke ĝi
> komenciĝis, sed ne finiĝis. Tio signifas, ke la ago aŭ stato okazas ĝuste nun,
> aŭ ke ĝi okazas kutime, aŭ ke la afero validas ĉiam:

La unua frazo kaj la dua frazo estas paradoksa. "ĝi komenciĝis, sed ne finiĝis"
kaj "[...], aŭ ke ĝi okazas kutime, aŭ ke la afero validas ĉiam" kontraŭdiras
unu la alian.

La Ekzercaro de la Fundamento §12 enhavas:

> Kvin kaj sep faras dek du.

Ĉi tio estas ekzemplo de la sentempa aspekto. La adiciado de kvin kaj sep ne
estas okazaĵo. Ĝi ne estas reala. Ĝi ne komenciĝis. Ĝi ne daŭras.

Se oni havus tre malrapidan kalkulilon, kaj tajpas "5+7", tiam atendas la
respondon, oni povus diri "Kvin kaj sep faras dek du." ("Five and seven are
making twelve."). Sed, se ne estas tiel, la frazo ne estu en la *present tense*;
ĝi estu en la *gnomic aspect*.

Do, ni povas konkludi, ke Zamenhof eraris kiam li skribis "present tense", kaj
ke li vere celis, ke la finaĵo "-as" povu uzati kiel la *present tense* **aŭ**
kiel la *gnomic aspect*, kiel la parolanto volas.

## La ekzistado de la sentempa uzo de "-as" plursencigas kelkajn frazojn.

> Mi pensas, ke ekstere ludas hundidoj.

Kion ĉi tio signifas? Oni povas traduki ĉi tiun frazon al la angla kiel ajna el
la du jena frazo:

> **Sentempa:** I think that, outside, puppies play.

> **Nuntempa:** I think that there are puppies playing outside.

La "-as" finaĵo de Esperanto estas plursenca - ambigia.

Êc se oni aldonas iun adverbon kiel "ĝenerale" aŭ "nun", ĝi akoraŭ estas
plursenca:

> Mi pensas, ke ekstere nun ludas hundidoj.

> **Sentempa:** I think that, outside, puppies now play.

> **Nuntempa:** I think that there are now puppies playing outside.

> Mi pensas, ke ĝenerale ekstere ludas hundidoj.

> **Sentempa:** I think that, in general, outside, puppies play.

> **Nuntempa:** I think that there are generally puppies playing outside.

Se oni volas priskribi ja nuntempan okazaĵon, oni povus uzi la *present
continuous tense* kiel la angla:

> Mi pensas, ke ekstere estas ludantaj hundidoj.

Sed, se oni volas priskribi sentempan okazaĵon, oni devas tute fidi la
kuntekston por senplursencigi. **Fakte, mi ne povas elpensi kiel diri ĉi tiun
frazon sentempe sen duobla senco.**

Eĉ "Mi pensas, ke ekstere hundidoj emas ludi." povus kompreniti kiel la
nuntempa: "I think that there are puppies outside who have a tendency to play.".
Estus iom stranga kompreni ĝin tiel, tamen se mi ne eraris, ĝi estus ĝusta
interpreto laŭ la gramatiko de Esperanto.

Ĉar la nedifinita artikolo ne estas necesa, "hundidoj" povus kompreniti kiel aŭ
"some indefinite number of puppies" aŭ "puppies, in general". Do, "Hundidoj
ludas." povus kompreniti kiel aŭ "Puppies play." aŭ "There are puppies
playing.". Se oni ĉiam devus uzi la nedifinita artikolo kiam oni scribas
nuntempe, tiam ĉi tiu problemo povus solviti de la evitado de la nedifinita
artikolo kiam oni scribas sentempe.

## Sentempa aspekto en Esperanto

Interese, efektive ekzistas la sentempa aktiva participo (*gnomic aspect active
participle*) en Esperanto, malgraŭ ke Esperanto ne havas (ekskluziva) sentempa
aspekto. Oni povas vidi ĝin en la vortoj "studento" kaj "prezidento".

Ankaŭ, Esperanto ne oficiale havas kondicionalaj participoj, sed pere de
anologio kun la aliaj Esperantaj participoj kaj la kondicionala verba finaĵo
"-us", la kondicionalaj participoj "-unta" kaj "-uta" derivitis (kvankam, ili
estas tre malofte uzataj).

Do, kial ne laŭ la alia direkto? Oni povus derivi la sentempan finitivan verban
finaĵon "-es" el la sentempa aktiva participo "-enta".

|  | Finitiva | Aktiva participo | Pasiva participo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pasinta | -is | -inta | -ita |
| Nuntempa | -as | -anta | -ata |
| Venonta | -os | -onta | -ota |
| Sentempa | (-es) | -enta¹ | / |
| Kondicionala | -us | -unta¹ | -uta¹ |
| Volitiva | -u | / | /² |

¹ Efektivaj, sed maloftaj kaj ne oficialaj

² "-enda" kaj "-inda" estas tre similaj al volitivaj pasivaj participoj, sed ne
ekzakte

Do, oni povus diri "I think that, outside, puppies play." kiel:

> Mi pensas, ke ekstere lud**es** hundidoj.

Ankaŭ, oni povus diri:

> Kvin kaj sep far**es** dek du.

Kvankam, en tiu lasta ekzemplo, ĝi estas sennecesa, ĉar ĝi estas jam klara pro
la kunteksto (se vi ne havas tre malrapidan kalkulilon).

## Do...

Mi ne celas proposi ke ni ŝanĝu Esperanton.

La plursenceco de la finaĵo "-as" ne estis problemo dum pli ol cent jaroj.
Preskaŭ ĉiam, kiel en la franca, estas sufiĉa kunteksto por senplursencigi.

Mi tamen pensas, ke ĉi tiu temo troviĝigas interesajn demandojn.

- Kiel alimaniere oni povas klare diri sentempe? Kiel oni povas diri "I think
  that, outside, puppies play." Esperante? Ĉu la finaĵo "-es" estus utila?
- Ĉu estus akceptebla uzi la ne oficialan finaĵon "-es"? Ĝi ne estus laŭ la
  Fundamento; sed, ĉu ĝi estus kontraŭ la Fundamento?

Demandoj rilatitaj:

- [Can I use the Present Tense for events regarded at the present as immutably
  fixed?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/235)
- [Can you write "Mi baldaŭ foriras" instead of "Mi baldaŭ
  foriros"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/232)

Answer (score 2):

Oni povas klasifiki verbojn laŭ diversaj kriterioj, laŭ modo (ekz. reela, imaga, ebla), laŭ tempo (nun-, pasinttempa)… aŭ laŭ aspekto, kies signifo ege varias inter lingvoj. Esperanto ne havas aspekton, kiu montrus "generalan veron anstataŭ specifan okazaĵon". Se vi volas esti preciza, Esperanto havas aspekton por priskribi perfektecon, sed ni ne pritraktu tion nun.

Principe oni povas kombini ĉiujn formojn de "esti" ("esti, estas, estis, estos, estu, estus") kun ĉiuj ses adjektivaj participoj ("-inta/anta/onta/ita/ata/ota"), kio donas al ni 6 * 6 = 36 kunmetitajn verboformojn. Pravas, ke Zamenhof ofte uzis tiajn verboformojn, sed dank' al [Kazimierz Bein](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazimierz_Bein) (Kabe), unu el la plej grandaj stilistoj dum la frua periodo de Esperanto, ni plejparte uzas simplajn verboformojn. Estas ja pli facile uzi ilin, kaj fakte kelkaj kunmetitaj verboformoj estas apenaŭ uzeblaj.

Ĉar oni uzas la verbon "esti" en la kunmetitaj verboj, tiuj montras staton – anstataŭ agon – kaj ĉi tial oni nuntempe plejparte uzas ilin, kiam oni priskribas, kion okazis samtempe kun alia ago.

- Ekstere estis hundidoj ludantaj, kiam…

Do laŭ la nuntempa lingvouzo kutime sufiĉas "Mi pensas, ke ekstere ludas hundidoj." Se vi nepre bezonas precizigi, ĉu vi celas kutimon aŭ ion, kiu ĵus nun okazas, vi aldonu vortojn kiel "(ĵus) nun, kutime" ktp.

Notu, ke la vortoj "studento" kaj "prezidento" estas neniaj kunmetaĵoj, sed la radikoj estas "student/" resp. "prezident/".

Answer (score 0):

Persone, kio finaĵon de la sentempa verb-tempo, mi simple elektus la plej ĝeneralan adverban finaĵon -e.  Mi konservus la finaĵon -es en tiu nuna signifo kiun jam havas ĝi ĉe la tabelvortoj je -es, tiodire en signifo poseda.

Mi simple permesus a unu uzi verbo-devenajn adverbojn, tiaj kiel ni jam ilin konas, tio kio aliajn verb-formojn pli konatajn.  La tendenco latenta jam estas en kelkaj esprimoj tiaj kiel "Klare ke mi venos.  Surpizante tamen ke Mario invitis min".  En ĉi tiu okazo estas permesite anstataŭigi "klaras, surprizantas" per laŭaj adverboj je -e.  Kial ne ĝeneraligi tiun permeson al kiaj ajn participoj?

En kia ajn frazo, foresto de verbo kun ĉeesto de participa adverbo signifus relativa-tempa verbo, rilate al aliiu verbo en la frazo aŭ sub-frazo plej proksima.

Ekzemple : mi pensas, ke ekstere, ludante hundidoj.  Mia kuzo ne veninte, mi decidis iri al la festo sola.

Tiu-maniere, uzante adverbajn participojn kun "esti" subkomprenita, oni povus uzi verbajn formojn multe malpli pezajn por esprimi la tempoj kompleksaj je esti + participo.  Tre ĝenerale tiuj duvortaj verboj je esti + participo troviĝas en sub-frazoj subordigitaj, aŭ cirkonstancaj.

Oni simple tekstus : "Mi ne povos veni.  Mi laborante."  Anstataŭ "Mi estas laboranta".

Teme pri la totala sendetermino de tempo, kiel ekzemple en matematiko, mi simple uzis la abstraktan, transtempan participon je -ent- jam ekzistantan en kelkaj nomoj, kiel "prezidento".  Prezidento estas homo pri kiu oni ne scias ĉu tiu nun estas prezidanta, prezidinta, aŭ prezidonta.  Oni povus ankaŭ uzi la verban nomon nudan je adverbiga -e, se ne rezulte dusenceco (se este du verba-devenaj adverboj senpere sin-sekvantaj, kio estas tre rare, la unuo estu la adverbo propre, kaj la sekva la relativa-tempa verbo).

Via ekzemplo do donus : kvin kaj sep farente dek du.  Aŭ kvin kaj sep fare dek du.

Sed en la ne-rekta parolo, por pli klare signifi la senimplikon de la parolanto en kio lio raportas, mi simple uzis infinitivaj verboj.

Teme pri via ekzemplo, Mi pensas ke ekstere ludi hundidoj.

Mi konservus la finaĵon -es por la senco posesiva, sed por etendi ĝin multe pli ampleksen trans la tabel-vortoj, Modele de la Angla, Sveda aŭ Germana posesiva vort-konstruaĵo. Nome, aldonante s al kiu ajn adverbo je e, oni povus konstrui posesivon, kiel "Matenes kafon mi nun prenas, kaj poste mi ĝuos Parizes vidindaĵojn kaj finine renkontos Maries amikojn."

Mi ĉi tiel ĵus uzante la jam ekzistantajn ilojn ofertatajn de la konata Esperanto, sed en okazoj ĝis nun ne-eldonitaj.

La transtempaj participoj je -ent- starigas problemon, tamene.  La problemo estas ke ne povas tiel formiĝi pasiva participo je -et-, ĉar tiu estas la finaĵo diminutiva.  Sed oni povas uzi tiu-sence la finaĵo -an plene harmonie kun ĝia senco pli konata de aparteneco, tiel harmonie kiel "de" ankaŭ signifas la agenteco kaj la aparteneco.  Ekzemple : dungi, dungento (ne grave ĉu li dungas, dungos aŭ dungis), dungano (ne grave ĉu li estas, estos aŭ estis dungata, dungota aŭ dungita).  Ĉi-prie, jam estas konata k tre uzata la esprimo "ne grave", ĉu ne?  -ento signifas pli propre iu kiu rolas en agado sen necese havi spertecon aŭ alvokiĝon en tia agado.  Ludento ne estas ludisto.